# What happens if I delete my own question?

Tags: support, deleted-questions

I suppose that if I delete a question I have asked those who have gained reputation by answering that question (even if the question has been closed) will lose the upvotes on that particular answer.
Are there any other options to have that question disappear without interfering with other people's reputation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can delete your own question only if it has no answer or a single answer with no upvote. This restriction is in place because deleting a question also deletes the answers, which may contain valuable content.

Once a question is deleted, it is no longer returned in search results or visible in your profile except to moderators (even you have no special privilege regarding your own deleted questions), and it can only be viewed by users with the [moderator tools privileges](https://french.stackexchange.com/privileges/moderator-tools) if they somehow find the URL to access it. The same goes for deleted answers, except that you can view your own deleted answers and they are visible to you on your own profile. See the [deletion FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that-actually-mean) on the main meta site for more information.

If a question is deleted by community votes or moderator intervention, then the reputation gains and losses from that question and its answers are nullified. This may not appear immediately, because your reputation total is cached; you can recalculate your own reputation by visiting [the reputation audit page](https://french.stackexchange.com/reputation) and hitting the button at the end of the page.

If you regret having asked a question, you can ask a moderator to delete it. However, we generally do not oblige when the question has answers, because once you have posted a question (or an answer, for that matter), it belongs to the community, not just to you. All Stack Exchange posts are licensed under the [Creative Commons Attribution-ShareAlike license](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/), which grants everyone a non-revocable license to reproduce the contents with attribution. If you do not want your name associated with the post, you can request that your name be dissociated as per clause 4.a of the [license](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/legalcode). On Stack Exchange, do this by flagging your post; note that if the post has been reproduced outside Stack Exchange, it is up to you to contact each distributor.

---

Tu ne peux effacer unilatéralement ta propre question que si elle n'a pas de réponse ou une réponse qui n'a pas reçu de vote positif. La raison de cette restriction est qu'effacer une question efface aussi les réponses qui peuvent avoir un intérêt en elles-mêmes.

Si une question est effacé, elle n'apparaît plus dans les résultats de recherche ni sur le profil du demandeur, sauf aux modérateurs (le demandeur n'a pas de privilège particulier concernant ses propres questions effacées). Le contenu de la question n'est visible qu'aux utilisateurs qui ont le [privilège « moderator tools »](https://french.stackexchange.com/privileges/moderator-tools), s'ils parviennent à obtenir un lien vers la question. Il en est de même pour les réponses effacées, sauf que l'auteur de la réponse peut toujours visionner ses propres réponses et voit apparaître des liens vers elles sur son profil. Pour plus d'information, consulter la [FAQ sur l'effacement](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that-actually-mean) sur le site méta principal (en anglais).

Si une question est effacée par un vote de la communauté ou par un modérateur, les gains et pertes de réputation associés sont nullifiés. Cette nullification peut ne pas être immédiate car les totaux de réputations ne sont pas recalculés systématiquement. Tu peux recalculer ta propre réputation en cliquant sur le bouton en bas de la page d'[audit de réputation](https://french.stackexchange.com/reputation).

Si tu regrettes avoir posé une question, tu peux demander à un modérateur de l'effacer. Mais en règle générale les modérateurs n'effacent pas les questions qui ont des réponses, parce qu'une fois publiée, une question (ou d'ailleurs une réponse) appartient à la communauté et pas seulement à son auteur. Tous les messages sur Stack Exchange sont publiés selon la licence [Creative Commons Attribution-ShareAlike license](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/), qui autorise toute personne à reproduire le contenu pourvu que l'attribution soit préservée. Si tu ne veux pas que ton nom reste associé à un message, tu peux demander à ce que ton nom soit dissocié en vertu de la clause 4.a de la [licence](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/legalcode). Sur Stack Exchange, une telle demande passe normalement par les modérateurs (donc par un drapeau, le bouton `flag`) ; note que si le message a été reproduit hors de Stack Exchange, c'est à toi de contacter chaque distributeur.

Comment: Merci pour cette réponse qui semble faire un tour complet de la question !